# Deleting duplicate equations from a list of equations

Tags: list-manipulation

Here is a list of algebraicly identical equations, and I like to delete all the duplicate equations from this list and get only two equations. I tried the following:

```
Clear[ss];
listEqs = {
   x + y == x^2 + z,
   y + z == x^2 + z,
   x + y == z + x^2,
   y + z == z + x^2,
   x^2 + z == x + y,
   z + x^2 == x + y,
   x^2 + z == y + z,
   z + x^2 == y + x
   };

DeleteDuplicates[listEqs]
```

I got:

```
{
 x + y == x^2 + z,
 y + z == x^2 + z, 
 x^2 + z == x + y,
 x^2 + z == y + z
}
```

Can someone tell me how to reduce the list to only two equations?

**EDIT 1**

I noticed a misunderstanding of my question. Here is a second list:

```
listEqs = {
   y + z == x^2 + z,
   a + b == k + g, 
   x + y == x^2 + z, 
   b + a == g + k,
   x + y == z + x^2,
   a + b == g + k,
   y + z == z + x^2,
   x^2 + z == x + y,
   z + x^2 == x + y,
   x^2 + z == y + z,
   z + x^2 == y + x};
```

The `code`:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[listEqs, MemberQ@Level[listEqs, -1]]
```

picks the first element of the list, which is not what I asked. I want the following list to be the output of the `code`:

```
{
y + z == x^2 + z,
a + b == k + g,
x + y == x^2 + z
}
```

Basically, I just want to pick the non-identical equations from the list. The desired equations can be placed in the middle, end or beginning of the list. The position of the equations are not the issue.

Comment: `listEqs // Simplify // Union`

Comment: @BobHanlon: Your proposal is not quite what I want since it creates new equations by cancelling the common terms on both sides of the equations, a result of `Simplify` command. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[listEqs, Reduce] (* or *)
DeleteDuplicatesBy[listEqs, Sort]
```

> {x + y == x^2 + z, y + z == x^2 + z}

For the longer input list:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[listEqs2, Reduce]
```

> {y + z == x^2 + z, a + b == g + k, x + y == x^2 + z}

Comment: It is a typo. Sorry for confusion, but your answer is the right one and it works for me. Thank you very much.